# Using a DIM statement within an IF/THEN Block - is the variable allocated if the condition fails?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Trying to be as efficient as possible...I would like to know when or if a variable is actually allocated in VB.NET inside of an IF/THEN block that fails.

Here's the statement block

```
IF MyCondition then

   dim myVariable as String

   myVariable = "FOO"

end if
```

If MyCondition fails is the variable actually allocated anyway when the procedure/function is called?  I know it won't be set to "FOO" but is memory allocated anyway?  I know that in this instance the impact is insignificant but with very large objects it could be.  I'm trying to prevent the allocation of a very large resource if it's not necessary.
Thanks

Comment: Why would you do this? Did you deduce by measurement/profiling that this causes a significant performance impact/bottleneck in your actual, running code? If no, why do you care? By the way, in most sane languages, the if statement block has scope, so I would expect the variable not to be allocated when the condition is false.

Comment: if the condition fails then you dont have to worry about the allocation as it will remain empty.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be any memory allocation if the if block is not executed. Since the resource (or an object representing it) is never created, there is no need to put it on the heap. You can easily test this by using the Profiling Tools that ship with Visual Studio. Write a small test programm like the one below:

```
Private Sub Execute()
    If allocateResource Then
        Dim resource As List(Of String)
        resource = Me.AllocateHugeResource
    End If
End Sub

Private Function AllocateHugeResource() As List(Of String)
    Dim ret As New List(Of String)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 100000
        ret.Add("Large string for tests")
    Next
    Return ret
End Function
```

You can start the profiling process for the block as provided above. You can change the allocateResource to true or comment the resource declaration and AllocateHugeResource() and compare the results.